# Spark ARIMA Model Example Error

Tags: time-series, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to run the provided ARIMA model example (Spark spark-ts library) with the ARIMA test data using Java API based on 0.4.0 jar. I am using "ARIMA.autoFit(ts, 1, 1, 1);" for fitting the model.

However, I get two warnings as below, after which execution halts without any further progress or errors:

```
WARN BLAS: Failed to load implementation from:   com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeSystemBLAS
WARN BLAS: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeRefBLAS
```

Tried Google & installed  "libgfortran3", but to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by building the jar from scratch via Maven rather than using the pre-built jar. Also, I built it on the Ubuntu machine where Spark runs.